# Multiple separate apache daemons on same machine

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I would like to ask a question, regarding whether it is possible to have multiple separate Apache daemons running on the same machine.
I do not refer to multiple apache processes. I know this is doable. I am talking about completely separate daemons. 
I am familiar with the concepts of VirtualHosts, and know how to run multiple websites on the same machine, but this is not what I need.

In detail, I am running a web application on a machine. An apache configuration files directs the web requests to the relevant location, or wsgi app.
However, I need to setup a reverse proxy on the same machine. The configuration file of the reverse proxy will be constantly updated with more and more entries. For this reason, I would like to have a separate apache daemon to run the reverse proxy, so that any possible syntax error on the reverse proxy's Apache configuration file, will not affect/crash the web application.
First of all, is this the way to go? Or is there another way to isolate the 2 applications(web app, reverse proxy), so that they don't affect each other?
If yes, how is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: Eventually I realized that 2 separate apache daemons will be an overkill. I think it's easy to mess up in that way.
Therefore I went for the option of separate config files. Each config file will correspond to a _./deploy_ script. This script will first validate all apache configuration files (using _apachectl configtest_) and only if they are all valid, will restart the apache server.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this - each daemon needs its own config file and (very important) different TCP ports that they listen on. You can't have multiple processes listening on a single port.

Comment: How is this achieved though? And, when you want to start/stop one of the daemons, how do you specify with one?

Comment: I've seen it done with parallel install directories - you would have /opt/apache1 and /opt/apache2 (for example). To start/stop, you run the command from the proper directory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 separate daemons, this may be done with port-based virtualhosts.

Comment: What do you mean? Still in this case, an error in one .conf file will affect the other app, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I've read your question inattentively.

If you install apache from source, just install 2 separate installations in 2 separate directories: /opt/apache2_webapp and /opt/apache2_rproxy.

If you want to use package manager, the simpliest way is to install one of servers into chroot. For example, in Debian/Ubuntu there is very convenient [Multistrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap) tool.

If you want to use the same package for running 2 separate servers, you should copy init script, settings directory, pid files directory, log directory, data directory with other names, for example in Debian/Ubuntu:

```
cp -r /etc/init.d/apache2 /etc/init.d/apache2_rproxy
cp -r /etc/apache2 /etc/apache2_rproxy
cp -r /etc/default/apache2 /etc/default/apache2_rproxy
cp -r /var/run/apache2 /var/run/apache2_rproxy
cp -r /var/log/apache2 /var/log/apache2_rproxy
cp -r /var/www /var/www_rproxy
```

Then change all paths in new init script and config files, try start/stop new init script to fix possible errors, and add new init script to required runlevels.

P.S. IMHO using 2 separate daemons is overkill. You may set up port-based virtualhost solution, and create script, that will run `apache2ctl configtest` before each reverse proxy config change and discard this change if test fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very thorough response. I can see it becoming a big mess with 2 Apache instances, so I will try to avoid it :)